# Searching for dataframe columns that contains needed substring

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to search for dataframe columns which can be present in dataframe. Column names are like SOMETHING_result. They all will have _result in common.

I really haven't tried anything yet, but i hope it is possible without using handmade functions with some inbuilt functionallity of pandas.

Comment: Have you tried `df.filter(regex="_result$", axis=1)`?

Comment: df.filter(regex="_result$", axis=1) Really worked thank you stranger!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [B Remmelzwaal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17200348/b-remmelzwaal)'s suggestion in the comments, `df.filter(regex="_result$", axis=1)` worked.